# Does "6514" have a meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was hoping someone may know if "6514", posted as a social network app status, has any meaning at all?

Comment: 6:留(stay; keep)/有(have); 5:我(me; I); 1:一(whole; one); 4:世(life)

Comment: Do you know the "someone"? if you do, I think you can ask him. I used to just put some random numbers there. (I'm not saying this is some random number)

Comment: @user16115 That's what I thought as well, this should be posted as an answer.

Comment: also very popular: 5211314 (我爱你一生一世) I will love you for life and eternity.

Comment: Sometimes  my friends also use "886" to represent "拜拜了" or "拜拜"

Answer (score 2):

6514 is not one of the popular numbers like 521(我爱你) or 1314 (一生一世), so the meaning is not clear.

I tend to think it could mean something else than Chinese.

If it really means something, it could be

- 搂我一次： 6 -> hug, 5 -> me, 14 -> once